# H1 not getting any style, but h2, h3, ... h6 are

Tags: html, css, tags

I'm using Skeleton V2.0.4 to create a landing page, but for some reason my  is not getting the styles quite right. These are the only lines referring to it:

```css
/* Typography
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300; }
h1 { font-size: 8.0rem; line-height: 1.2;  letter-spacing: -.1rem; }
h2 { font-size: 3.6rem; line-height: 1.25; letter-spacing: -.1rem; }
h3 { font-size: 3.0rem; line-height: 1.3;  letter-spacing: -.1rem; }
h4 { font-size: 2.4rem; line-height: 1.35; letter-spacing: -.08rem; }
h5 { font-size: 1.8rem; line-height: 1.5;  letter-spacing: -.05rem; }
h6 { font-size: 1.5rem; line-height: 1.6;  letter-spacing: 0; }

/* Larger than phablet */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  h1 { font-size: 5.0rem; }
  h2 { font-size: 4.2rem; }
  h3 { font-size: 3.6rem; }
  h4 { font-size: 3.0rem; }
  h5 { font-size: 2.4rem; }
  h6 { font-size: 1.5rem; }
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h5>Heading 5</h5>
```

When i run in Safari or Chrome, it looks like this:

[image]

What is going on?

Comment: Have you inspected the element in the browser to see what rules it applies…?

Comment: I tried your code in a few browsers at different sizes, and the styling seems applied correctly. Are you sure there's nothing else going on?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a "barbaric" way of doing it but try

```
h1 { 
 font-size: 8.0rem!important;
 line-height: 1.2!important; 
 letter-spacing: -.1rem!important;
 }
```

Maybe some other css file is overwriting your current stuff.

Comment: The "!important" trick solved it, but kinda messed up the responsive properties.

Comment: Add important for the rest h1 on the responsive

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, but still no idea what why it was happening.

I checked it and the only possible difference was that my html had another css style sheet linked to it, though it was **completely empty** (seriously, no lines at all!). After deleting the link, the  tag started working normally.

It's solved, though i still have no idea why it only affected  and not the pother heading tags. Bug maybe?

Comment: Now I added the style sheet back after adding "body {background: blue}", H1 worked fine. I deleted it and left it empty again.

PLOT TWIST: H1 remained fine.

Seriously, wth?